# How do operating systems and applications display emojis?

Tags: fonts

Can vector fonts used in Windows or Mac OS handle multiple colors? How do they render emojis that have multiple colors?

Are emojis treated just like another code point and use the same typography system as other characters, or is the block of emojis singled out and specially handled?

I also notice that browsers on the same OS render emoji characters separately from the OS, unlike other characters where the browser simply uses the fonts installed in the OS. Is this observation correct?

Answer (score 0):

The emojis are rendered according to different platform but are defined by same charsets.
for example in utf-8  is 128516. Hence every platform will render similar type of emojis for same code. Color and style differs according to platform